# Theorem of homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have one question about group theory.

Our professor told us that there is a standard type of problems when it comes to proving that two groups are isomorphic. And he was always using the First theorem of homomorphism to prove them. But in our exam they gave us such problems, without teaching us the theorem and so I tried to prove them by constructing some images from one group to the other.

But my question is: Can we prove that, for example,
$H/\mathbb{R}_+ \cong \mathbb{C}_9$ for $H=\{ z ∈ \mathbb{C}^*
:|z|^9  = z^9\} $ without this theorem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There seem to be some formatting errors.

Comment: @user839372 Are there still any errors?

Comment: @Jut3 I made some edits. Please have a look that I did not change the content of your question. Could you also let us know what $\mathbb{C}_9$ is?

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you for the additional edit. And yes, this is the set of all roots of the equation $x^9=1$ which are nine

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Yes you can prove that $H/R_+\simeq\mathbb C_9$ without the isomorphism theorem. You can go with brute force and take the map $$z\mathbb R_+\mapsto\frac{z}{|z|}$$ and prove that it is 1-1 onto

Comment: @Jut3: the group of ninth roots of unity is usually denoted $U_9$.

Comment: I think you're allowed to use the first isomorphism theorem in the exam.

Comment: @Berci Of cource I am allowed, but that is not the point...lol

Comment: @Alessandro Thank you for the answer. I have a question, $z\mathbb{R}_+$ means all the positive  integers or all positive integers from 0 to 8?

Comment: No, when you have a group $G$ and a subgroup $K$ (in this case, $G=H$ and $K=\mathbb R_+=\{\lambda\in\mathbb R:\lambda>0\}$), then $G/K=\{xK:x\in G\}$, where $$xK=\{xk:k\in K\}$$in this case $z\mathbb R_+$ are all the complex numbers in the form $\lambda z$, with $\lambda$ a positive real number